# Парсинг: регулярки или PHPhtmlDOM?

Tags: php, dom

Доброго времени.. Ранее парсил только через регулярки. Теперь мне подсказали, что можно иначе это делать . Хотел бы узнать, есть ли преимущества парсинга через DOM перед регулярными выражениями ?
Спасибо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но можно получить инфу на русском языке, т.к переводчик не дает понять, о чем там мысль изложена  ? ))
ну или в двух словах

Comment: Изложил основную мысль в ответе. А вообще, это каноничный ответ, который вы ещё не раз встретите, потому что желающие попарсить html регулярками находятся ежедневно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Произвольный html просто невозможно описать регулярными выражениями, это другой тип грамматики ([контекстно-свободная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) против [регулярной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Поэтому и нужно пользоваться стандартными парсерами - там уже учтены все нюансы, код становится читаемым и, что самое важное, работает так, как нужно.

Регулярные выражения можно использовать, только если у вас небольшой кусок html с чётко определённой структурой, которая никогда не меняется. Но зачем?